# ng-include is ignoring onload directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an onload directive in an ng-include, and it seems like it's being completely ignored.  The `<h1>` block is included in my HTML, but `test()` is not being called.  No errors, no log, nothing.  Thanks.

Here's a pretty simple example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Testting</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js">    </script>
  <script>
  var myApp = angular.module('testApp', []);

  myApp.controller('MyMenu', ['$scope', '$element', function($scope, $element) {
    $scope.username = 'David';
    $scope.test = function() { console.log("Testing!"); };
  }]);
  </script>

</head>
<body ng-app="testApp">
  <div ng-include="'views/global-nav.html'" onload="test()"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and views/global-nav.html:

```
<h1 ng-controller="MyMenu">Hello {{username}}!</h1>
```

Comment: `div`s don't have `onload` attributes. Now I don't know anything about Angular, so it could be that I'm wrong, but you could try moving the `onload` to the `body`.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared test() in your controller 'MyMenu', so the test() function is in the scope of the controller. But the way test() is called here it onload would search for test() in its own scope, but since it is not within this scope(it is in scope of controller which is the child of div containing onload) it doesnt work.

Check out below

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
   <title>Testting</title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js">    </script>
   <script>
   var myApp = angular.module('testApp', []);

   myApp.controller('MyMenu', ['$scope', '$element', function($scope, $element) {
     $scope.username = 'David';
     $scope.test = function() { console.log("Testing!"); };
   }]);
   </script>

 </head>
 <body ng-app="testApp">
   <div ng-controller="MyMenu">
   <div ng-include="'views/global-nav.html'" onload="test()"></div></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and views/global-nav.html:-

```
<h1>Hello {{username}}!</h1>
```